# Should we memzero an IPC pool-pointer handle before exporting into it?

Tags: memory-management, cuda, ipc

In the CUDA sample [`streamOrderedAllocationIPC`](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/2_Concepts_and_Techniques/streamOrderedAllocationIPC/streamOrderedAllocationIPC.cu) we see, at some point, the following:

```cpp
// Get the opaque ‘bag-of-bits’ representing the allocation
memset((void *) &shm->exportPtrData[i], 0, sizeof(cudaMemPoolPtrExportData));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemPoolExportPointer(
    (cudaMemPoolPtrExportData *) &shm->exportPtrData[i], ptr));
```

This baffled me somewhat, since the [Runtime API documentation for cudaMemPoolExportPointer()](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY__POOLS.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY__POOLS_1gb2f607ca635363ea7d1ecbf61b725168) does not suggest one needs to zero-out the memory of the exported handle before performing the export.

So, why do we have this `memset()`? Is it really necessary, or kind of a superstition, a charm against evil spirits, so to speak? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This memset is not necessary, however it is important to note there is no guarantee that `shm->exportPtrData[i]` is initialized if `cudaMemPoolExportPointer` fails (returns a value different from `cudaSuccess`).

The idea behind the memset in this sample is that, regardless the success status of `cudaMemPoolExportPointer`, the child process can try to import it and will fail gracefully if it cannot. In this specific case, without the 2 memsets this sample has (one at the beginning, one that you pointed out), we could imagine a scenario where calling `cudaMemPoolImportPointer` on uninitialized memory would cause undefined behavior. If you guarantee that `cudaMemPoolExportPointer` succeeded, there should be no need for this.

Comment: I also believe the memset is unnecessary, but - what makes you certain?

Comment: I added more information regarding the intent behind the memset in this sample, hope that helps!

Comment: I guess I can buy that argument... :-)